# Keypress firing buttonclick when not supposed to

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6

This code worked OK under Delphi XE4. Under XE6 any char I enter in cxTextedit fires the button.

```
procedure TForm1.cxTextEdit1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
if Key=chr(13) then
Key := #0;
AdvGlowButton1Click(Self);
end;
```

What could be wrong ?

Comment: Consider using _proper indentation_ in your **source code**. It does not only make your sources "nicer", but provides instant insight to such problems. (If you had the `if` block indented, you instantly had the impression that `AdvGlowButton1Click(Self)` is outside of the block.) You can use the answer of _Remy Lebeau_ as a short reference or see [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#Allman_style) for my personal favourite style. :)

Comment: Some coding tutorials also **suggest** that execution blocks of one instruction (like your `Key := #0;`) should also be marked with block markers (`begin` and `end` in Pascal and `{` and `}` in C style languages) to avoid mistakes like yours, but that seems to be pretty much unnecessary typing, and can be avoided if you rarely make mistakes like that. Don't forget: _Shorter/compact source code does not necessary means shorter/faster executables._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you showed clicks the button on every character typed, in ALL Delphi versions.  If you are trying to click the button only when ENTER is typed, then you are missing a required `begin/end` pair:

```
procedure TForm1.cxTextEdit1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
  if Key = #13 then
  begin // <-- add this
    Key := #0;
    AdvGlowButton1Click(Self);
  end; // <-- add this
end;
```

Comment: I try it in both XE2 and XE6 and it works fine for me exactly as I showed it. There is no `Word` in this code, which makes me think that maybe you have something in your project that is mapping `Char` to `Word`.